# Implement generic trait for all Containers and Iterators

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a trait that determines, if the elements of a container or iterator are monotonic.

My implementation looks something like this:

```
pub trait MonotonicIterator<T> {
    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool; 
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool;    
}

impl<'a,T,I> MonotonicIterator<&'a T> for I
where
    I: std::iter::Iterator<Item=&'a T> + Clone
{ ... }

pub trait Monotonic<T> {
    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool;    
}

impl<'a,'b:'a,T:'b,C> Monotonic<&'a T> for &'b C
where 
    &'b C: IntoIterator<Item=&'a T>,
    <&'b C as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: Clone
{
    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<&'a T>) -> bool {
        return MonotonicIterator::is_monotonic_up(self.into_iter(), cmp)
            || MonotonicIterator::is_monotonic_down(self.into_iter(), cmp);
    }
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<&'a T>) -> bool {
        return MonotonicIterator::is_monotonic_down(self.into_iter(), cmp);
    }
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<&'a T>) -> bool {
        return MonotonicIterator::is_monotonic_up(self.into_iter(), cmp);
    }
}
```

I'm not actually implementing the algorithm twice here, but I'm using the trait MonotonicIterator in the implementation of Monotonic, but still, this looks like a lot of code duplication just for the definition of Monotonic and MonotonicIterator. What I originally wanted to do is something like the following, but the compiler complains about conflicting implementations:

```
pub trait Monotonic<T> {
    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool; 
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<T>) -> bool;    
}

impl<'a,T,I> Monotonic<&'a T> for I
where
    I: std::iter::Iterator<Item=&'a T> + Clone
{ ... }

impl<'a,'b:'a,T:'b,C> Monotonic<&'a T> for &'b C
where 
    &'b C: IntoIterator<Item=&'a T>,
    <&'b C as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: Clone
{
    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<&'a T>) -> bool {
        return self.into_iter().is_monotonic(cmp);
    }
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<&'a T>) -> bool {
        return self.into_iter().is_monotonic_down(cmp);
    }
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<&'a T>) -> bool {
        return self.into_iter().is_monotonic_up(cmp);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to solve this and have just one single trait that I can use for containers **and** iterators?

Comment: What is `Comparator`? Please provide a [MRE] for your second example.

Comment: Actually, please provide [MRE]s for all of your code. We can't help you if you only show us half the context.

Comment: I see your problem now. Usually, every type that implements `Iterator` also implements `IntoIterator` automatically. I guess the idea of implementing for `&'b C` wasn't that good after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a better implementation than the first one.

I don't think it's possible to get the potential collision fixed. This is a workaround that is as good as it will get.

That said, there's a bunch of potential improvements in your code. You are using way too many lifetimes, and you should use associated types at some places instead of generics.

Like this:

```rust
pub trait Comparator<T> {
    fn ge(&self, a: T, b: T) -> bool;
}
pub trait MonotonicIterator {
    type T;

    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool;
}

impl<I> MonotonicIterator for I
where
    I: Iterator + Clone,
{
    type T = <I as Iterator>::Item;

    fn is_monotonic(self, _cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool {
        false
    }

    fn is_monotonic_down(self, _cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool {
        false
    }

    fn is_monotonic_up(self, _cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

pub trait Monotonic {
    type T;
    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool;
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool;
}

impl<'a, C> Monotonic for &'a C
where
    &'a C: IntoIterator,
    <&'a C as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: Clone,
{
    type T = <&'a C as IntoIterator>::Item;

    fn is_monotonic(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool {
        MonotonicIterator::is_monotonic(self.into_iter(), cmp)
    }
    fn is_monotonic_down(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool {
        MonotonicIterator::is_monotonic_down(self.into_iter(), cmp)
    }
    fn is_monotonic_up(self, cmp: &dyn Comparator<Self::T>) -> bool {
        MonotonicIterator::is_monotonic_up(self.into_iter(), cmp)
    }
}

struct U32Comparator;
impl Comparator<&u32> for U32Comparator {
    fn ge(&self, a: &u32, b: &u32) -> bool {
        a.ge(&b)
    }
}
impl Comparator<u32> for U32Comparator {
    fn ge(&self, a: u32, b: u32) -> bool {
        a.ge(&b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![4, 5, 6];
    println!("{}", x.is_monotonic(&U32Comparator));
    println!("{:?}", x);

    let x_iter = x.into_iter();
    println!("{}", x_iter.is_monotonic(&U32Comparator));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts! I'm still at the beginning of learning Rust and these are my first steps trying to solve simple problems. That's why my code might still be very verbose and suboptimally structured, but your examples/improvements are very informative and helpful!